# Check whether some character has some Unicode character property in Python

Tags: python, unicode

How can it be checked in Python whether some "character" (more precisely, code point or length-one string) has some [Unicode character property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property)?

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in `unicodedata` module?

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, I have. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58668162/check-whether-some-character-has-some-unicode-character-property-in-python#comment103640250_58668348.

Comment: @snakecharmerb The linked question has a solution only for the script. I’m interested in a general solution that can be used to query every property defined in the Unicode standard.